# Updating child entities in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

Is it correct to update a child entity when it's not part of its Aggregate Root?

Lets consider an ecommerce site. There's a product entity, which has multiple variants. If we consider that the product is a T-shirt, then a product variant might be a t-shirt with a color of White or Green.

```js
class Product {
  id: number
  slug: string
  description: String
  variants: ProductVariant[]
}

class ProductVariant {
  name: string
  quantity: number
  price: float
  images: string[]
}
```

Lets exclude the non-variant related rules and focus on the variants.

1. A variant cannot exist on its own, it must be part of a product
2. A product can have up to 10 variants
3. A variant must have at least one image, name, quantity and price

Now, how does a variant come into existence? Well, according to pt.1, our product must implement a `product.addVariant(variant: ProductVariant)` method, as the variant cannot exist on its own.

Since the variant contains its own logic, we can implement a factory method. For simplicity, we can assume a private constructor, so the implementation can be like

```js
class ProductVariant {
  private constructor(...) {}

  public static create(productVariantProps): ProductVariant {
    // Validate input, if valid
    return new ProductVariant(productVariantProps)
  }

  // Rules for adding new images
  addImage(productVariantImage) {...}
}
```

And the way that the product variant can come into existence can be like so

```js
const product = await ProductRepository.find(...)
cosnt variant = ProductVariant.create({ 
  name: "White", 
  quantity: 1, 
  price: 25.50,
  images: [ ... ]
})

product.addVariant(variant)
await ProductRepository.save(product)
```

Error handling is excluded for simplicity, the `addVariant` method can return a nullable error, for example, but it can be implemented in multiple ways.

Now, this example contains a product, which enforces validation rules according to the number of variants that can be added to it, and a separate ProductVariant entity, which enforces validation rules according to itself.

In the UI, we used to have one product form for the product and all its variants were edited /created/deleted on the same page. The UX team decides that this is very complex for our customers and it would be better if we have a dedicated page for editing a variant.

So, we were editing the variants here: `/products/edit/:productId`, and now we'd like to have to go here `/products/edit/:productId/:variantId` to edit a variant.

Now, if a variant exists, all its rules/business logic are encapsulated in the `ProductVariant` class, so we should be able to just fetch it from the database, make our changes, and save it through the repository.

However, the ProductVariant is a child entity of the Product Aggregate Root.

I'm inclined to do something to the lines of

```js
const variant = await ProductRepository.findVariant(req.params.variantId)
// make the changes
await ProductRepository.save(variant)
```

But should I? Should it be the ProductRepository? Shouldn't I only save Aggregate Roots?

From what I know, the more proper way to achieve this would be

```js
const product = await ProductRepository.find(req.params.productId)
const variant = product.getVariant(req.params.variantId)
// make the changes to the variant
await ProductRepository.save(product)
```

But

1. It involves more work
2. Unnecessary data is fetched for the given operation ( one product might have many child entities, like variants, images, which have locales etc ), when I know for certain I'm only interested in this one variant

Edit: Sorry for the broken code examples, I thought I would write it in Typescript, so that its more understandable, but I'm not 100% familiar with it and very tired. Hopefully the point is clear.

Comment: you might consider handling Variants as Products of their own, with a weak reference to the original Product.

Comment: Well, if I was to do that, how would the "Each product must have between 1 and 10 variants" rule be enfored?

Answer (score 1):

As long as Product and Variant don't have any business rules that will affect ProductVariant, I see no reason to load extra data through the aggregate root. If this decision creates a problem in the future, just change it. Keep a pragmatic mind and don't fall into analysis paralysis.

Splitting your UI into different parts is a good idea. A Task-based UI makes it easier for you as a developer to know what is happening in the UI.

With this in mind, creating and changing ProductVariant can be implemented as a command from the UI that only handles this entity. I would use the same repository as Product for this.

I know you didn't ask for feedback on your REST API, but I recommend that you build the URLs like this /resource/:id/resource/:id/(action). This way, you rarely need to use the action part of the URL because you use the HTTP verbs to decide if you are doing a PUT (update), POST (create) or DELETE. Also, it's easier for users of your API to know what the ID represents.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I don't actually have this specific problem, its pseudo code, and our API uses GraphQL. I just wanted to provide enough context so that the problem becomes easier to understand, but thank you for the hint. I found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. A variant cannot exist on its own, it must be part of a product

This one can be implicitly enforced in code by making sure no code paths allow it. See answer about #2.

> 2. A product can have up to 10 variants

As we can see, the constraint that spans many variants is their count, but not the variant states per se. That means you could simply track the count in `Product` and involve `Product` in the creation and removal process of a `ProductVariant`. All other code paths would deal with the `ProductVariant` directly, which is an AR of it's own.

e.g.

```
// Service layer
addProduct(productId, name, quantity, ...) {
    transaction {
        product = productRepo.productOfId(productId);
        variant = product.addVariant(name, quantity, ...); //tracks count & enforces rule
        variantRepository.save(variant);
    }
}

renameVariant(variantId, newName) {
    transaction {
        variant = variantRepo.variantOfId(varitantId);
        variant.rename(newName);
    }
}
```

> 3. A variant must have at least one image, name, quantity and price

This rule can be enforced in the `ProductVariant` AR itself.

Comment: The usage of this seems a bit odd, having the ability to edit a variant by itself, but its creation/removal is a job of another aggregate root ( the product one is creating it ). Also, I guess it doesn't work for auto-incrementing database columns, as when the Product AR creates the Variant, it doesn't know what its id would be after it is saved, so it cannot associate itself with it.

Comment: It's not odd, it's perfectly aligned with business rules and factory methods on ARs for creating other ARs is pretty common. About late ID assignation though that's usually to be avoided in DDD. If you want to delegate ID creation to the DB you can still expose a `nextId` method on the repository which uses a sequence.

Comment: If a variant was to have a `purchase(quantity: number)` method, which, when called, would reduce the `quantity` property of the variant and the `totalQuantity` of the Product AR ( which is outside of its scope ) then would that mean that the are bounded together and should not be used in the way that we are discussing? I'm trying to grasp how I should divide entities, because, if I follow your example, I can do the same for Variant/Product images and not load them eagerly when selecting the Product/Variant AR from the database.

Comment: Well the rule you are describing was out of scope of the question. I proposed a design that aligned with the rules specified. If the rules are changing then the design must change as well. The `totalQuantity` could perhaps be made eventually consistent instead of strongly consistent. Perhaps the quantities would exist on `Product`, but the rest of the info would exist on `Variant` so you'd have a `Product.ProductVariant` entity within `Product` but also a `ProductVariant` AR with the rest of the info.

Comment: Therefore, purchase would be `product.purchase(variantId, quantity)`, but changing the image of a variant would be `variant.changeImage(...)`.

Comment: Yes, I know it wasn't in the initial question, it was an attempt to further clarify where to draw the lines. When there's a relation like that and a new variant must be created, who is tasked with the creation part of it? Suppose the ProductVariant has a static factory method, should I pass the props to `product.addVariant(variantProperties)`, that method then calls `ProductVariant.create(variantProperties)` and returns an error, if occurred, or should the ProductVariant be created outside, and passed to `product.addVariant(productVariant)`?

Comment: @DiyanSlavov To ensure consistency (e.g. not forget to call `product.addVariant(variant)`) I'd favor passing the attributes to `product.addVariant()`, but in this case since `ProductVariant` is it's own AR could could always consider the latter, but the service could forget to inform the `Product` that a variant got added so I think I still prefer the former, unless you make this eventually consistent.